# How to merge data within a JSON file using contains as the match?

Tags: json, jq

I have a text file that contains the following JSON output. I would like to be able to merge the data whenever "IP" is contained within Groups. I would like to use jq or sed/awk.  I am open to any other bash commands.

```
{"Front":[
{"Name":"new.domain.com-80", "Out":"8.8.8.8", "In":"192.168.2.2:80", "W Name":"new.domain.com-80", "Groups":"192.168.3.29:80 192.168.3.30:80"},
{"Name":"new.domain.com -443", "Out":"8.8.8.8", "In":"192.168.2.2:443", "W Name":"new.domain.com-443", "Groups":"192.168.3.29:443 192.168.3.30:443"}
]}
{"Back":[
{"REC":"", "IP":"192.168.3.30", "Host":"new2.domain.com", "Info":"Worker5 MD: Data source - Owner: Q"},
{"REC":"Q", "IP":"192.168.3.29", "Host":"new3.domain.com", "Info":"Worker5 MD: Data source - Owner: Q"},
{"REC":"Q"}
]}
```

If IP is contained within Groups then add Host & Info.
We can ignore REC

Expected Output:

```
{"Front":[
{"Name":"new.domain.com-80", "Out":"8.8.8.8", "In":"192.168.2.2:80", "W Name":"new.domain.com-80", "Groups":"192.168.3.29:80 192.168.3.30:80", "Host":"new2.domain.com,new3.domain.com", "Info":"Worker5 MD: Data source - Owner: Q,Worker5 MD: Data source - Owner: Q"},
{"Name":"new.domain.com-443", "Out":"8.8.8.8", "In":"192.168.2.2:443", "W Name":"new.domain.com-443", "Groups":"192.168.3.29:443 192.168.3.30:443", "Host":"new2.domain.com,new3.domain.com", "Info":"Worker5 MD: Data source - Owner: Q,Worker5 MD: Data source - Owner: Q"}
]}
```

Comment: Why aren't the IP addresses in `Groups` stored as an array?  Why `"Groups":"192.168.3.29:80 192.168.3.30:80"` instead of `"Groups":["192.168.3.29:80",  "192.168.3.30:80"]`. ?

Comment: It was just part of the formatting output. I could have that changed if that will help.

Comment: Both Groups in Front has 192.168.3.29, how do we know which one to merge? And wrt your above comment, with jq, it wouldn't help, checking a string's containment in another script is easier than in an array

Comment: It would need to be added to both if there is a match on contains. Which is ok.

Comment: But your expected output implies otherwise. An object can not have duplicate keys; like `{ "Host": "foo", "Host": "bar" }` is invalid JSON. Are you sure you know what you want or am I missing something here?

Comment: See https://jqplay.org/s/CB9qompUSt This way we lose `new2.domain.com`

Comment: I see what you are saying. Any ideas on how to merge those values when a match is found based on the IP?

Comment: What was the problem when you tried to do it?

Comment: I updated the correct output above.

Answer (score 2):

The following assumes that the Front and Back objects are presented in that order on STDIN or in a file; with this assumption, the following program should be invoked with the -n command-line option.

```
input as $front
| input as $back
| ($back|INDEX(.Back[]; .IP) | map_values({Host,Info})) as $dict
| $front
| .Front[]
  |= reduce ($dict | keys_unsorted[]) as $k (.;
       if (.Groups | contains($k)) then . + $dict[$k] else . end)
```

I’ve used `reduce` to iterate over the IP values as doing so provides flexibility in case you want to handle conflicts in some particular way.

### Invocation

One possibility:

```
jq -n -f program.jq input.json
```

Comment: You assume correct that the Objects are listed in that format with a text file.  Can you help me understand how to run this?

Comment: Here is the file I am using https://pastebin.com/raw/AxNeZute  
I am getting 

jq: error: INDEX/2 is not defined at <top-level>, line 3:
| ($Back|INDEX(.Back[]; .IP) | map_values({Host,Info})) as $dict
jq: 1 compile error

Comment: Your jq is evidently very old.  If you cannot readily upgrade, then google for the def of INDEX/2 and copy it into the top of program.jq (e.g. google for: def INDEX builtin.jq)

Comment: Thank you @peak , I was able to get your program to run using Kali of all things.  As  oguz-ismail pointed out new2.domain.com does get written over. Anyway to preserve that?

Comment: Yes. It depends on what you want.

Comment: I updated the expected output format above. Can you help me produce that type of output? @peak